# Lots of spam despite google recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I recently installed Google recaptcha on my website but despite that, I get waves of spam regularly (waves of about thirty spams, once a week).

I think that recaptcha is pretty solid, so I think my code is the problem but I do not see where.

Here the code in order to have your opinions. Thank you very much for your advice

HTML

```
<head>
[...]
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>          
[...]
</head>

<body>
[...]
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<PUBLIC_KEY>"></div>
[...]
</body>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
    $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret_key);
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

if (isset($response) and $response != null and $response->success) {
    send();
}
```

LIB

https://github.com/appleboy/ReCAPTCHA/blob/master/php/recaptchalib.php

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form with every fields filled except the reCaptcha? If the form successfully validated, it means that your code is wrong. If the form rejected it, then you code is all good. There is a lot of bot (human and automated) out there for others to easily bypass captcha. You may want to implant other method (hidden fake fields etc) to prevent bot.

Comment: You may want to give a newer version a try: https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA